# Change readable portions of file with unknown characters

Tags: c#, file, text, encoding

I'm trying to read a text file that has readable and unreadable characters. It opens easily in any text editor.  Most of the text characters are unknown characters and the part I want to change is readable.

The file looks like this
readable1 gibberish readable2 gibberish. 
I want to change readable2

If I use the following techniques they seem to return only readable1. They do not give the same output as dropping it on a text reader.

```
readFile(){
string sr=new StreamReader(path);
contents = sr.ReadToEnd();
//or
contents=File.ReadAllText(path);
}
```

I tried a few encodings ASCII, Unicode, UTF8, UTF32 but nothing seems to match the same output as dragging onto a text editor.

```
byte[] bytes  = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
string str = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

Is there any way to get it to return all the characters and just modify the readable characters?

Comment: Is this a C# question? Please add the relevant language tag.

Comment: Your editor is guessing at a character encoding. Do you have to guess, too? What's the specification for the file layout?